# Programmatically add dependencies to external project in Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

First, all of this code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/pcclark4/GradleDependencyTest, which may make it easier to follow what I'm about to describe.

I have a unique problem in which a main module loads classes at runtime using reflection if they exist. *Project1* contains two modules: **Lolol**, the main application module that uses reflection to load an instance of a class that implements TestInterface, and **LibLib**, the module which contains the TestInterface interface.

Using the settings.gradle file in *Project2*, I manually go up a directory then back down into the *Project1* directory in order to define those projects. Therefore, I can open up the settings.gradle file and see *Project2* as well as the two modules from *Project1*. The module **Rofl** in *Project2* is a library module which depends on **LibLib** from *Project1* so I can define a class that extends TestInterface.

If I were to open *Project1*, I can still build it even without *Project2*, because it truly doesn't care if that class is there or not. It will just load it if its available. However, if I open *Project2*, I need the **Lolol** module to see **Rofl** as a dependency when it is built. I do NOT want to manually insert "compile project(':Rofl')" into **Lolol's** build.gradle file every time I decide to add an extension. Instead, I would prefer if I could programmatically tell **Lolol**, using **Rofl's** build.gradle file, that it needs to build **Rofl** as a dependency.

I have tried adding this inside of Rofl's build.gradle:

```
project(':Lolol').dependencies {
    compile project(':Rofl')
}
```

No success, however.

I hope I've worded everything correctly. I greatly appreciate any suggestions! The directory structure is below, but like I said, it might be easier to just view my GitHub project.

```
├── Project1
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── LibLib
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── com
│   │                   └── eowdaoc
│   │                       └── liblib
│   │                           └── TestInterface.java
│   ├── Lolol
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── com
│   │                   └── eowdaoc
│   │                       └── lolol
│   │                           └── TestActivity.java
│   └── settings.gradle
├── Project2
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── Rofl
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── com
│   │                   └── eowdaoc
│   │                       └── rofl
│   │                           └── TestClass.java
│   └── settings.gradle
```

Comment: Don't know the answer but upvoted for preparing an example on GH!